# Getting overflow error for double variable with one decimal in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, double, overflow

I am simply trying to learn VBA coding and when i am running a simply code that assigns a variable as a double, assign a value to the variable, and then a message box for said variable. If I am too debug the code line by line, I will get an overflow error when it comes to assigning the variable a value. However, if I simply compile the entire code all at once it has no problem.

I am not sure what to do at this point as even assigning simply a 6 to the variable gives me an overflow error

```
Sub myVariable()
Dim blah As Double
blah = 6.4
MsgBox blah
End Sub
```

So if I debug this code line by line, I will get an overflow error when "blah = 6.4" is highlighted and cannot go any further. If I hit F5 and compile the entire code, the msgbox comes up with 6.4 as it should.

I should also mention that i am doing this in Excel and on a Macbook and when I tried the same piece of code on a PC it worked no problem.

[Tried opening a new workbook and even deleted the old one and had the same issue, heres a screenshot to show the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH5zd.png)

Comment: No repro. If you add just this code to a new workbook, do you get the same error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem either.  Something else in the workbook?

Comment: Tried a new workbook and had the same issue, I should mention that I am doing this on a macbook and through excel if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

Can try being explicit about the literal value:

blah = 6.4R

Comment: What do you mean?  `blah` is a double and `6.4R` will be interpreted as a string and won't compile the way you have written it.